# Use BetterTouchTool keyboard short cut to find all folders in Finder with the tag "red"

Tags: macos, keyboard, finder, applescript

I use the tag "red" to tag all folders and files on my machine which I want to quickly access.

I am now trying to setup a keyboard command e.g. <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>opt/alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to open in Finder all my files and folders with a red tag. Yes, I know it is possible by clicking on the "Red" tag on the sidebar, but I want to do it using a keyboard command.

I have BetterTouchTool installed on my Mac, created the keyboard combination above and have set it up to trigger to run an AppleScript when I am in Finder.

What sort of AppleScript can I run to achieve my purpose above?

Comment: The edit was to fix grammatical errors and to make your question easier to read and understand. If someone has an answer for you, they'll add it.